# Delete post media except featured image

Tags: post-thumbnails

I'm working on site where post except 'featured image' has also other images. Under certain circumstances I need to delete all images except 'featured image'. Which one the most convenient way to do it? Is it possible to do via `delete_post_media()` function or I should write custom query?
Thanks.

Comment: delete_post_media() is not a core function I guess, http://wordpress.org/support/topic/delete-images-attached-to-page-post, you have to write a custom one, the above link might be of help

Comment: Yes, of course, I've gone in wrong direction......ok, thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If someone has clashed with such problem, I solved it in this way:

```
$attachments = get_posts( array(
    'post_type'      => 'attachment',
    'posts_per_page' => -1,
    'post_status'    => 'any',
    'post_parent'    => $post_id
) );
$thumbId = get_post_thumbnail_id($post_id);
foreach ( $attachments as $attachment ) {
    if($thumbId != $attachment->ID) wp_delete_attachment( $attachment->ID, true );
}
```